# Copy text data from another application

Tags: c#, copy, postmessage

I need to recieve data from some win application (not mine). Application window can be inactive at this time.
Data I need is represented in table, so I am unable to use WM_GETTEXT, WM_COPY because they retrieve text only from texboxes, textareas, etc.
I can manually make a selection at this table and all I need is just copy text from this selection by emulation of Ctrl+C to copy data to clipboard. I tried to send that key sequence this way

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x11, 0x001D0001);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VkKeyScan('c'), 0x002E0001);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, VkKeyScan('c'), 0x002E0001);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VkKeyScan('c'), 0xC02E0001);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, 0x11, 0xC01D0001);
```

But also have no success. This works great for Notepad but not for my table.
Is there any other way to get text data from there?

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? Like DataGrid, GridView, html table?

Comment: How do you know you have the right window handle?

Comment: @odie, Yes, it looks like gridview. But actually it is not .NET application.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error, I got handle by Spy++

Answer (score 0):

You mention c#, so I'm going to assume the other win app is also .Net in which case you could get the data using techniques such as: [Hawkeye - The .Net Runtime Object Editor](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/)

Comment: No, other application is not a .NET one. Tried Hawkeye and it returns nothing.